# Baudline app crashes after opening XQuartz: OSX 10.11.6

Tags: x11, osx-elcapitan, xquartz

Running an XQuartz dependent app called Baudline on OSX 10.11.6. Was working fine before upgrading XQuartz, but after a fresh install of both, Baudline crashes upon opening XQuartz. Getting the following report:

**Error: attempt to add non-widget child "dsm" to parent "baudline" which supports only widgets
logout**

Kind thanks ahead for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Solved. A la http://michaelgalloy.com/2016/11/11/problems-with-xquartz-2-7-11-on-macos.html, the following terminal commands fixed the widget breaks in 10.11.6:

**sudo mv /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib{,.bak}**

**sudo cp /opt/X11/lib{/flat_namespace,}/libXt.6.dylib**

Happy DSP-ing to all you Baudline fans.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that does not require changing system files (which may break other apps that use XQuartz) is to start Baudline with the following terminal command:

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/flat_namespace /Applications/baudline.app/Contents/Resources/baudline`

Similarly to the other answer, it let's the app load `flat_namespace` version of the XQuartz library. The drawback is that Baudline started that way will not have separate icon in the Dock.